# Switch between images when space bar pressed (js)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

So I am creating a video game where an icon moves with pc controllers. Now, I want that when I press the space bar, my icon (spaceship which moves with controllers) switches between other icons. I have written a code which does not work. Could you guys please help me? What I would like to have would be that when space bar is pressed, it switches between four images and at the end, it returns to the original style. I would really appreciate if you could maintain the same switch() command (what I mean is to have nothing really complicated if possible).

Here is the code for controllers:

```
let display = document.getElementById("body").style.width
let rect = document.getElementById("icon-p1")
let pos = {top: 85, left: 600}
const keys = {}
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {keys[e.keyCode] = true})
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {keys[e.keyCode] = false})
const loop = function() {
if (keys[37] || keys[81]) {pos.left -= 10}
if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {pos.left += 10}
if (keys[38] || keys[90]) {pos.top -= 1}
if (keys[40] || keys[83]) {pos.top += 1}
rect.style.left = pos.left + "px"; rect.style.top = pos.top + "%"}
let sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40)
```

Images:

```
<img src="Photo/Spaceship.png" id="icon-p1" style="display:none">
<img src="Photo/Spaceship1.png" id="icon-p2" style="display:none">
<img src="Photo/Spaceship2.png" id="icon-p3" style="display:none">
<img src="Photo/Spaceship3.png" id="icon-p4" style="display:none">
```

My code for switching images which does not work:

```
let spaceship1 = document.getElementById('icon-p1');
let spaceship2 = document.getElementById('icon-p2');
let spaceship3 = document.getElementById('icon-p3');
let spaceship4 = document.getElementById('icon-p4');
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 32) {
event.preventDefault()
switch() {
case 0: rect = spaceship2; spaceship2.style.display = 'block'; spaceship1.style.display = 'none'; break;
case 1: rect = spaceship3; spaceship3.style.display = 'block'; spaceship2.style.display = 'none'; break;
case 2: rect = spaceship4; spaceship4.style.display = 'block'; spaceship3.style.display = 'none'; break;
case 3: rect = spaceship1; spaceship1.style.display = 'block'; spaceship4.style.display = 'none'}}})
```

Thanks

Comment: You aren't passing anything to `switch()` and therefore comparing nothing to `0`, `1`, etc. You also need to `break;` after a case, or `case 0` for instance will run through all the other cases, too. Also, you can use a single <img> element instead and simply switch its `src`.

Comment: Okay thanks but could you please provide some code?

Comment: Can please someone help me?

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question a 2nd time, especially if there's an answer accepted by you [Switch between images when space bar pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259437/switch-between-images-when-space-bar-pressed)